# Where to store client_secret.json from Google API in an Android Application?

Tags: android, api, security, google-api

I think client_secret.json has very sensible information, I don't like to store it as a plain text on a .json file, but is the example that Google gives you: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/quickstart-java

Where  should I store that file?

Answer (score 1):

After being incapable to read a file on assets or raw folder (really is that difficult? compression, readers everywhere, permission...) I decide to use an StringReader with the file contents on the code and use that reader to create the needed GoogleClientSecrets.

Not so cool, but works and I think this data is pretty unmutable in time so I'm not worry about could be a bit more difficult to maintain.

So code looks like:

```
    Reader r = new StringReader("{\"installed\":{\"auth_uri\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\"token_uri\":\"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token\".... ");

    try {
        clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,  r);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```